# How do i combine EL+JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I'm currently learning JSTL+EL and so far it's been going good , but I got stuck.

I have this code:

```
<% StoreItems items = new StoreItems(); %>
<% Vector<Item> itemsList = items.getItemsByCategory(category); %>
```

And I'm having trouble converting it to JSTL+EL
What I've tried to do is:

```
<jsp:useBean id="items" class="db.StoreItems"/>
<jsp:useBean id="itemsList" class="${items.getItemsByCategory(param.category)}"/>
```

But i think i might be completely off

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to be missing is the MVC architecture. JSPs should be view components. Their unique responsibility should be to find some beans stored in request attributes (the model), and generate the HTML markup from these beans.

Getting items from the database and storing them in the request attributes should be done in Java classes, invoked from a controller. The controller could simply be a servlet, or it could be an action of your preferred MVC framework (Spring MVC, Stripes, Struts 2, etc.).

You shouldn't have scriptlets in JSPs. You shouldn't be using jsp:useBean tags.